# jQuery getJSON in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make two json calls from twitch for each channel in an array of twitch channels. For some reason the array items are undefined in the second json call.

```
var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "medrybw", "brunofin", "storbeck",       "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff"],
 streamerList = $('ul.list-group');

for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {

 $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamers[i], function(streamData) {

  $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + streamers[i] //undefined, function(channelData) {

   var listItem = $('<li/>').addClass('list-group-item').appendTo(streamerList);
   var nameLink = $('<a/>').html(JSON.stringify(channelData.display_name)).appendTo(listItem);

  });
 });
}
```

Comment: Use `$.each(streamers, function(i, streamer) ...)` so the variables will be in the closure.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly